# MVC3 - How to send form data to an action which takes an object using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action which takes an view model object

```
[HttpPost]
public String Edit(UserGroupEditViewModel model)
{/* ... */}
```

Now I want to send form data async using jQuery

```
$('#user_dialog .edit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var ug = $(this).parent('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: urlEditUserGroup,
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: ug,
            //datatype: 'json',
            //contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
             }
        });
  });
```

However, I'm not able to receive form data.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part is failing?  Is the ajax call actually calling the correct action method, but just not populating the model, or is it not even reaching your action method?

Comment: It reaches the action, but unable to send form data

Comment: First thing to try is `var ug = $(this).closest('form').serialize();`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot It works, but why parent fail.

Comment: `.closest(selector)` looks up the DOM hierarchy at `.parent()` then `.parent().parent()` then `.parent().parent().parent()` etc. until it finds an ancestor which matches the selector. `.parent()` failed because your target element is nested at more than one level within the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the form is not being serialized, try (as mentioned by @Beetroot-Beetroot)

```
var ug = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

 data: {UserGroupEditViewModel :ug},
```

more over you can assign an id or a class to your form so that the form can be selected easily for the serialization.

try debugging your code by putting

```
 var ug = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
console.log(ug);
```

to check if the serialization yields results.